# How to throw and mock exception in mockito and Junit5. And how to write test case for that

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

When the URL is wrong or something wrong with the response during third party API call in getMethodWithHeader this method will throw HttpClientErrorException so how to write a test case for this

**This is my main code method**

```
public JSONObject callRespectiveAPI(String url, String apiKeyAndPassword) {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    try {
        String accessToken = apiUrlUtil.getAccessToken(apiKeyAndPassword);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = apiUrlUtil.getMethodWithHeader(url, accessToken);
        String nextUrl = apiUrlUtil.getNextUrl(response.getHeaders());
        result = JSONObject.fromObject(response.getBody());
        result.put("nextUrl", nextUrl);
        
    } catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
        result.put("status", "404");
        result.put("message", "Not Found");
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

I want to throw HttpClientErrorException and test it

**This is the test code**

```
@Test
public void callRespectiveAPITest2() {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    object.put("success", true);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(object.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    when(apiUrlUtil.getAccessToken(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("accessToken");
    when(apiUrlUtil.getMethodWithHeader(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(response);
    when(apiUrlUtil.getNextUrl(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("nextUrl");

    assertEquals(true, shopifyService.callRespectiveAPI("nextUrl", "accessToken").get("success"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
when(apiUrlUtil.getNextUrl(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("nextUrl");
```

you can turn that into

```
when(apiUrlUtil.getNextUrl(Mockito.any())).thenThrow( ... )
```

and have that throw whatever you want.

Of course, you also want to adapt the *assertions* accordingly, for example to check for that 404 status and "Not Found" message.

But note, the real answer here is: read the documentation, and do your own research.